# assign a frame to an instance with geometry nodes of an animated object

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, animation-nodes, instances, loop

I want to «bake» each frame of an animated object on top of the other. The object consists of a layer of rectangles on the same plan that organizes themselves from a video. See changes in shapes, density, orientation and color in images. [image][image][image]

There was an addon that did the trick but it does not seems to work more recent version of Blender. (Animation Replicator with Offset (ARewO), 2014 https://www.blenderdiplom.com/en/downloads/537-arewo-gui-a-detailed-description.html) I tried to dowload older version an open my blender file, but it does not match.

I think that one option here is to associate a frame (with «Scene Time» nodes) to a specific instance of the stack in a loop that repeats itself for each of the layers instancing the base changing object.[image]

To objective is to create a mass of those stacked layers. See the result (made by hand) in the image. [image]